# If variable AND variable Then

Tags: vba

I found this procedure [here](http://codevba.com/visual-basic-source-code/files-vb/test_if_file_exists.htm#.XXq6EfkzaxA) for testing if a file exists:

```vb
Public Function FileExists(strFileFullPath As String) As Boolean
Dim lSize  As Long
    On Error GoTo HandleError
    lSize = -1
    If GetAttr(strFileFullPath) And vbDirectory Then GoTo HandleExit
    lSize = FileLen(strFileFullPath)
    FileExists = lSize > -1
HandleExit:
    Exit Function
HandleError:
    Resume Next
End Function
```

I was first tempted to correct that:

```
    If GetAttr(strFileFullPath) And vbDirectory Then
```

into:

```
   If GetAttr(strFileFullPath) = vbDirectory Then
```

but then surprisingly found that the result is the same.

Can someone explain how that first version is interpreted?

Comment: It tells you in the link: `The test with vbDirectory is to prevent a foldername to be considered as a file`. If you mean programmatically, it's the same as `vbDirectory=true`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `AND` here performs a bitwise comparison.

GetAttr(filename) returns a bitmask.

Changing it to `=` will only return the same results if the file is only a directory. If it is hidden, or archived, or a system directory, it would have a different value and they would no longer be equal. The bitwise comparison makes sure that at least the filename refers to a directory

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/getattr-function